# databinding oledb exception missing operator in the query

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, oledbconnection

CODE:

```
//this is in private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{string sql = "select * from doctofact WHERE (([doctofact].[docid]=" + l + " and     [doctofact].[1userid]='"+str6+"'))";
  da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con);
        cmd = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
        dt = new DataTable();
        BindingSource dsource = new BindingSource();
        dsource.DataSource = dt;
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
          dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;


        da.Update(dt);
      }


  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // edit button
    {
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;

        MessageBox.Show("Click on the cell you want to edit and change");
     }


      private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //save button
    {
        da.Update(dt);
        MessageBox.Show("The changes you made have been saved!");
    }
```

Now my datagridview shows what I want exactly so it simply means that the query 'sql' is working fine. The problem arises only when I edit and try to bind by clicking the save button. The error that I get is :

```
 oledb exception missing operator in the query Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(((? = 1 AND DocID IS NULL) OR (DocID = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND FactID IS NULL) OR (FactID = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND ArticleTitle IS NULL) OR (ArticleTitle = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND FactPreview IS NULL) OR (FactPreview = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND 1userid IS NULL) OR (1user'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to go through this link.
[Check This Link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database)

The problem is caused due to datatype mismatch

Comment: I used the same tutorial to write the query. Well if there was a problem with the datatype I believe even my Insert query wouldn't have worked. But it works fine I get to see what I need in my datagridview. The error looks like it's implying something simple though.